# How to populate a SharePoint list using SharePoint Mangement Shell?

Tags: list, powershell, list-item

Why does this code is working perfectly when I type it inside Sharepoint Management Shell and does not inside a PowerShell Script file (.ps1) ?

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue
$webURL = "http://myUrl"
$listName = "myList"
$web = Get-SPWeb $webURL
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$newItem = $list.Items.Add()
$newItem["myField"] = "myValue"
$newItem.Update()
```

I got the following error:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Actually it does insert some items inside the list but it replaces the last one by the new values instead of adding them at the end.

Comment: I run this script and it worked inside .ps1. Run your windows powersell as administrator. Then execute the command Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned. Finally run your .ps1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but It did not worked. I know it's working because i run it on a different list and there is no problems. I've created a custom list using Visual Studio but it doesn't work on this particular one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the characters encoding. It was set to something else than UTF-8. I saved my script in UTF-8 and it worked. My list display name had some special characters.